# How do I correct this "IndexError: list assignment index out of range in this code" that saves as index the number of each line of a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, append

This is the part of the code, and indicate the line that gives an error with a comment #THIS IS THE LINE.
in this case I want the list to store the line number of the txt, but it appears to me that this index is not even initialized.

```py
import re, random, os
from os import remove
from unicodedata import normalize


def name_and_img_identificator(input_text, text):

    #Quita acentos y demas diacríticos excepto la ñ
    input_text = re.sub(
        r"([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+", r"\1",
        normalize("NFD", input_text), 0, re.I
    )

    input_text = normalize( 'NFC', input_text) # -> NFC
    input_text_to_check = input_text.lower() #Convierte a minuscula todo


    #Inicializo listas vacias
    persons_names = []
    persons_identifier_img = []


    if (os.path.isfile('data_association/persons_names_file.txt')):
        persons_names_file_path = 'data_association/persons_names_file.txt'
    else:
        open('data_association/persons_names_file.txt', "w")
        persons_names_file_path = 'data_association/persons_names_file.txt'


    #Lo usare como un dato asociado
    if (os.path.isfile('data_association/persons_identifier_img_file.txt')):
        persons_identifier_img_file_path = 'data_association/persons_identifier_img_file.txt'
    else:
        open('data_association/persons_identifier_img_file.txt', "w")
        persons_identifier_img_file_path = 'data_association/persons_identifier_img_file.txt'



    with open(persons_names_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
        #positive_words.extend(textfile.readlines() + [""])
        persons_names.extend(textfile.readlines())
    print(persons_names)

    with open(persons_identifier_img_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
        #negative_words.extend(textfile.readlines() + [""])
        persons_identifier_img.extend(textfile.readlines())
    print(persons_identifier_img)



    regex_patron_00 = r"\s*\¿?(?:mi nombre es|me llamo|me llaman|me conocen como)\s*(:|)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"

    m = re.search(regex_patron_00, input_text_to_check, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

    if m:
        print("A")
        person_name = m.group()

        person_name = person_name.strip()
        #persons_identifier_img = persons_identifier_img.strip()
        persons_identifier_img = ""

        person_name_check = person_name + "\n"
        persons_identifier_img_check = persons_identifier_img + "\n"

        redefinition = False
        both_coincidences = False
        num_linea = None

        #try:
        if(1 == 1):
            with open(persons_names_file_path,"r+") as f:
                lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in f.readlines()]
                with open(persons_identifier_img_file_path,"r+") as g:
                    lineas_Association = [lineaA.strip() for lineaA in g.readlines()]

                    print (person_name)
                    #print (persons_identifier_img)
                    print (lineas)
                    print (lineas_Association)
                    print("B")

                    #Si no se encuentra palabra en el archivo txt
                    if (person_name not in lineas):
                        print("A1")
                        f.write(f"{person_name}\n") #Agrega la palabra al final del txt de palabras
                        num_linea = lineas.index(person_name)
                        persons_identifier_img = str(num_linea) + ".jpg"

                    #Si llegase a estar el nombre pero no la imagen (quizas la borraron)
                    #elif (person_name in lineas) and (persons_identifier_img not in lineas_Association):
                    elif (person_name in lineas):
                        print("A3")
                        redefinition = True #SI NO SE ENCUENTRA ENTRA LA REDEFINICION Y ESO ESTA MAL DEBERIA SER SI LA PALABRA SE ENCUENTRA Y LA ASOCIACION ES DIFERENTE
                        num_linea = lineas.index(person_name) #Obtiene el indice que indica la linea en donde se escribio la palabra en el txt
                        persons_identifier_img = str(num_linea) + ".jpg"


            with open(persons_identifier_img_file_path,"r+") as f:
                lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in f.readlines()]

                if (redefinition == False):

                    if(both_coincidences == False):
                        f.write(f"{persons_identifier_img}\n") #Agrega la definicion al final del txt de definiciones

                        answer_num = random.randint(1, 2)
                        if answer_num == 1:
                            #text = "Ohh vaya, no sabía que para jugar a " + str(word) + " necesitaría " + str(association)
                            print("No te conocia")
                        elif answer_num == 2:
                            #text = "Eso suena divertido, la verdad no sabía como jugar a " + str(word) + ", pero ahora se que para jugarle debería " + str(association)
                            print("No te conocia")
                    

                    elif(both_coincidences == True):
                        #text = "Ohh eso ya lo sabía, si quieres podemos jugar a " + str(word)
                        print("Ya te conocia")
                        both_coincidences = False
                        
                if (redefinition == True):
                    f.truncate(0)
                    f.seek(0)
                    lineas[num_linea] = f"{persons_identifier_img}\n" #Agrega la definicion sobreescribiendo la definicion que ya estaba en la linea coincidente con la del txt de palabras
                    f.writelines("\n".join(lineas))

                    answer_num = random.randint(1, 2)
                    if answer_num == 1:
                        #text = "Ohh vaya, la verdad no sabía que para jugar a " + str(word) + ", además de lo que yo ya conocía, también se necesita eso que me estas diciendo acerca de que " + str(association) + ", por lo que veo creo que eso que me dices parece tener sentido"
                        print("Identifique una nueva imagen con tu personal, osea asociada a tu nombre")
                    elif answer_num == 2:
                        #text = "Si lo que me dices es correcto y te estoy entendiendo bien, para jugar a " + str(word) + " se necesita " + str(association) + ", jaja la verdad es que yo tenía otra información acerca de eso, pero lo que me dices creo que tiene sentido"
                        print("Identifique una nueva imagen con tu personal, osea asociada a tu nombre")

                    redefinition = False
                    
        
            return text

        #except:
        else:
            print("V")
            return text


input_text_str = input("ingrese: ")
text = ""

name_and_img_identificator(input_text_str, text)
```

```py
  File "do_you_talk_with.py", line 124, in name_and_img_identificator
    lineas[num_linea] = f"{persons_identifier_img}\n"
  IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Why do you do `num_linea = lineas.index(person_name)` when you know `person_name not in lineas`? That'll throw a `ValueError`.

Comment: Also, you can replace the `elif person_name in lineas` with `else`. You already checked the inverse condition in the `if`, so `elif ...` is a waste of computation.

Comment: Please do some [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) first and condense your code down to a [mre]. 
[Step through your code](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953), or print suspected bad values and follow them back to where you think they went wrong. 
"Debug my code for me" is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953) In this case, clearly `num_linea >= len(lineas)`, and you can't assign to a list index that is greater than the max index of the list. Did you mean to _append_ to the list?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Sorry, is that when I synthesize the code so that it is shorter and the question is better focused, I modified my original code and there are some inconsistencies. If you want I put the complete code but, the problem is specifically in the list and its index that it does not find

Comment: Well, we cannot help you if we cannot run your code and reproduce your problem. This applies here because 1. `input_text_to_check` is undefined. 2. We don't have access to your filesystem and the file in `persons_names_file_path`. Please provide the expected [mre]. We should be able to paste your code into our environments and reproduce the problem. Make it **minimal**, so remove parts of your code irrelevant to the problem. Figure out what value of `num_linea` causes the error and where that value was set, and why.

Comment: Ok I put all de code, I apologize for not having it complete but in another question they told me not to put all the code and just put where the error was, that's why I did it.

Comment: **MINIMAL** does not mean _"all de code"_. Please read the links I shared. It's unreasonable of you to expect the people volunteering their time here to waste it reading line after line of code that is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Ok this code is all you need to run it, but I have a problem with the logic of the algorithm, If you can help me I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num_linea` is the line number containing a person's name in the `persons_names_file_path` file.

But then you try to access that same line number in the `persons_identifier_img_file_path` file.

The second file has fewer lines, and so the index is out of range.

Comment: How would I do to keep both lists at par, so I don't have one with a lower index than the other, I'm getting pretty messy with the logic of this algorithm

Comment: Make sure those files are in sync.  You haven't shown us how those files are created, so I can't give any specific answers.

Comment: I try with a -1 in this line of the code lineas[num_linea-1] = f"{persons_identifier_img}\n" but i get the same error

Comment: I have already put all the code, sorry but since I thought it was extensive I thought it would be annoying to put it in full, but you are right and I see that before I had omitted important details. I apologize but I already put everything